# Удаление из строки всех символов кроме цифр и символа +

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярное выражение, которое убирает все символы кроме цифр и символа `+`?

Comment: `/[^\d\+]/g`? (2 символа)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> /[^+\d]/g
> ```

- `[...]` - символьный класс
- `^` - инверсия, будем заменять "всё кроме"
- `+` - символ +, можно заэкранировать: `\+`, но внутри символьного класса это не обязательно
- `\d` - цифра
- `/.../g` - флаг global для replace - менять все вхождения

```js
let str = 'call: +7(123) 456-78-90';

console.log(str.replace(/[^+\d]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Плюс не экранирован.

Comment: А зачем его экранировать в символьном классе??

Comment: @Anamnian а зачем его экранировать в данном случае (в наборе символов)?

Comment: Вы правы, я ошибался. Не обязательно его экранировать. Хотя мне нагляднее с экранированием.

Comment: @vp_arth справедливости ради: на мой взгляд, `\+` действительно нагляднее. Но тут уж вопрос предпочтений.

Comment: @Regent если будет длинный символьный класс, можно его принять по ошибке за `+` квантификатор.

Comment: @Anamnian а почему в длинном? По-моему, в коротком `[\d+]` как раз спутать проще всего, если не знать как работает `+` внутри `[]`. А вот в `+\d` уже сложнее спутать

Comment: Это дело привычки: `\d+` слишком часто используется в других целях

Comment: @Regent Ну если будет к примеру такая регулярка `/(?:(?:\s*[+>~,]\s*|\s+)|[^:+>~,\s\\[\]]+(?:\\.[^:+>~,\s\\[\]]*)*)|\[(?:[^\\[\]]*(?:\\.[^\\[\]]*)*|[^=]+=~?\s*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'))\]|:[^\\:([]+(?:\\.[^\\:([]*)*(?:\((?:[^\\()]*(?:\\.[^\\()]*)*|"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')\))?/g`

Comment: @Anamnian ... то, значит, в какой-то момент разработки что-то пошло не так, раз появился такой регвыр :) Ибо сидеть разбираться и исправлять ошибки в таком выражении не хочется от слова "полностью". И, думается мне, `+` вместо `\+` в `[]` при его разборе будет меньшей из проблем

Comment: а если нужно все плюсы кроме плюса вначале?

Comment: удалить или оставить?

Comment: оставить толкьо плюс вначале и числа. остальные удалить

Comment: Это более сложный вопрос) Можно добавить ещё один `.replace(/(\d)\++/g, '$1')`, например.

Answer (score 5):

Пойдем от обратного, просто возьмем любой символ, кроме числа и +

```js
const regEx = /[^\d\+]/g;
const test = '123gybbrry45ybg6=789,m   er+'


console.log(test.replace(regEx, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение для гугл-таблицы, у меня получилось таким:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"\+[0-9]+")
```